# What effects are used to match this specific sample?

Tags: plug-ins, sampling, spectrogram

I want to recreate a sample used in the song "Promise Ring" by Death's Dynamic Shroud. The original sample used in the Promise Ring song is called "Soon as I get home", taken from the album "Tender Lover" by Babyface. I opened up FL studio, dragged in both songs, and placed them on the timeline at the moment they start singing the same verse. Also, I heightened the pitch and stretched the Death's Dynamic Shroud song to match Babyface's song respectively. This is what they look like side by side. Each sample is roughly 10 seconds long.
[image]

Sample 1: A sample used in the song "Promise Ring". It's pitched and shortened to match the original song it was taken from - "Soon as I get home" by Babyface.

Audio for Sample 1: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pTW9F_-OExl0Qm8mMd93ZWwaDz2k0ta5/view?usp=sharing

Sample 2: A verse in the song "Soon as I get home" by Babyface.

Audio for Sample 2: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OW_sy5GrMMXkjDmvB8CDHh7UPRqI-X_n/view?usp=sharing

I don't know much about spectrograms, but I can probably guess what's happening. The gain has increased and there seems to be a lot of reverb added in. I tried this approach in FL studio, however, they both sound drastically different. I tried adding limiters, flangers, and distortion plug-ins. But that didn't work.

Regardless, can anyone tell me what effects were added to Sample 2 to create Sample 1?

Much thanks.

Comment: Effects added in Adobe Audition or Audacity might also be possible.

Comment: From what I can hear in the two samples, you're on the right track. Just by ear, I think the chain was possibly an overdrive, then flange or chorus, then reverb. It sounds like they're all fairly light touches, so be gentle with them all. With so many components, it's going to be tricky to find the right balance. Just keep tweaking until you find it

Comment: I think I'm close, but the vocals always sound too close. In sample 1, it sounds wide and distant. I added a multiband compressor to separate the low bands and the high bands. It's helped some, but I was wondering if there's anything else I could add.